# How to set a default argument for a templated function parameter to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, default-arguments

I have a templated function where the only template parameter is used for passing a function pointer, and I want to be able to set a default argument (a specific function) to that parameter but it doesn't seem to work as I expected. Setting a default argument to the template parameter does not allow me to call the function with the defaulted argument omitted unless I make a separate overload instead. Is there a way to accomplish this using default arguments?

---

Here's what I tried at first, `validator` being the problematic parameter:

```
template <typename FuncT>
std::string ask_for(size_t arg_index, const std::string & prompt,
                    FuncT validator = Validators::is_not_empty,  // default does not work!
                    std::ostream & os = std::cout);
```

(`Validators` is a namespace containing helper functions intended to pass to this function.)

The last parameter `os` does react to the default argument as I expected; `ask_for(0, Validators::does_file_exist)` works with `os` being set to `std::cout`. 
But if I call `ask_for(1)` it does not call `ask_for(1, Validators::is_not_empty)` as I expected, instead it gives me this error trace:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'ask_for(int, const char [64])'
note: candidate: 'template<class FuncT> std::string ask_for(size_t, const std::string&, FuncT, std::ostream&)'
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'FuncT'
```

Shouldn't it be able to deduce the template parameter by the given default argument? Or am I misunderstanding how default arguments are implemented for template parameters?

However, I was able to get the expected behavior by writing a separate overload and calling it instead:

```
template <typename FuncT>
std::string ask_for(size_t arg_index, const std::string & prompt,
                    FuncT validator,   // no default here...
                    std::ostream & os = std::cout);

// ...overloaded version calls function with desired default argument
std::string ask_for(size_t arg_index, const std::string & prompt)
{
    return ask_for(arg_index, prompt, Validators::is_not_empty);
}
```

Is there a way to set a default argument for the templated parameter to a function pointer, or must I create a separate overload to achieve this? Would this be possible with a template specialization or if I remove the template parameter altogether and use a specific function pointer instead? 
I would like the default argument notation for readability, but I am mostly interested in efficiency.

Comment: Did you try `template <typename FuncT=decltype(Validators::is_not_empty)>...`, or whatever that function type actually is?

Comment: Alas, [default arguments cannot be used to deduce a template argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2783?view=msvc-170).

Comment: You must also give a default argument to FuncT, like `template<typename FuncT = decltype(Validators::is_not_empty)>`

Comment: And remember to call a template function with default template argument by `ask_for<>(...)` instead of `ask_for(...)`

Comment: W.E.Brown about [templated functions](https://youtu.be/NIDEjY5ywqU?t=203).

Comment: Okay, setting a default type to FuncT works, using the function pointer!
`template<typename FuncT = bool (*)(std::string, std::string &)>` I'm wondering will this instantiate a version of the template function at this declaration or at the first default call? And I don't need the explicit `<>` if I'm using C++17 or newer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default argument cannot be used to deduce a template argument, but you can also default `FuncT`.

```
template <typename FuncT = decltype(&Validators::is_not_empty)>
std::string ask_for(size_t arg_index,
                    const std::string & prompt,
                    FuncT validator = &Validators::is_not_empty,
                    std::ostream & os = std::cout);
```